# Linq to SQL DateTime contains string

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-4.5

I'm trying to match a partial string provided by the user to a nullable datetime using linq to sql. I have to match against criteria but I'm getting a linq to sql does not support .ToString() error.

Code I've tried:

```
query.where(x => x.myDate.HasValue && x.myDate.Value.ToString().Contains(searchValue);
```

I've also tried to split it out like similar to this:

```
query.where(x => x.myDate.HasValue && x.myDate.Value.Year.ToString().Contains(searchValue);
```

What I want is for a user to type a partial datetime string like "202" and it will check to see if the year, month or date has 202 in the value (In this case it'll filter to only show dates in the year 2020, 2021, 2022 etc.

The format that I expect the user to enter the date in is 2020-06-01.

I've tried several variations and I'm pretty stuck, if I could do a partial match on an int then I can rework the code to get away with it but not being able to do a simple .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") on the datetime its looking for in the database is very limiting.

I'd appreciate any help you can provide and I have looked through similar questions in stackflow but I haven't hit upon an answer I can use.

Comment: Looks like this is a case where using SQL directly is the better solution. If using LINQ, it looks like you're forced to run that kind of query on the client side, which may not be a realistic solution.

Comment: I wonder how useful this is. A value like "19" will match each date in 2019 (assuming your date range is limited, otherwise a lot more years) and each 19th of any month. Which actual question could that possibly answer? Just to mention one example.

Comment: Its a BR, off the top of my head it'll be for searching when you have a rough idea (A "see what sticks" type of search, if you will). My own preference would be to do a date range search but I'm not in charge of the decision.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `DbFunctions / EF.Functions` for this case.

**EF 6.2+ (.NET Framework)**

```
query.Where(x =>
    x.myDate.HasValue &&
    DbFunctions.Like(x.myDate.Value.ToString(), $"%{searchValue}%"));
```

**EF Core (.NET Core)**

```
query.Where(x =>
    x.myDate.HasValue &&
    EF.Functions.Like(x.myDate.Value.ToString(), $"%{searchValue}%"));
```

Comment: This is code running in framwork not core and I'm very restricted with the libraries I can use. (I'll add it to the OP)

Comment: @HQ216493 If you're using EF 6.2 there should be the equivalent of that method in the class called DbFunctions. I edited the answer with the sample for older version.

Comment: Thanks for the update, its appreciated, but I'm currently limited to .net-framework 4.5.2 for this particular application.

Comment: Also to add further clarification, the Linq to SQL is erroring on using .ToString() on the DateTime value. So when trying the DbFunctions approach it states "cannot convert from 'int' to 'string' for the p.myDate.Value.ToString() part of the DbFunctions.Like